# Determine Poker Table Positions - Sit'n Go Tournaments

Tags: javascript, arrays, poker

> Note: I do the javascript code according to the ajrwhite answer. Hope it helps someone.
>
> Link: http://codepen.io/eMineiro/pen/EKrNBe
>
> Open codepen console to see the examples working.

In poker we define player position according to the dealer. Like this:

[image]

*Blue: Small Blind and Big Blind positions*

*Green: Late and Dealer/Late positions*

*Yellow: Middle positions*

*Pink: Early positions*

So, assuming these two arrays:

```
players:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
positions:["bb","sb","btn","late","medium","medium","medium","early","early","early"];
```

In this case, "player1" is the "Big Blind", "player2" is the "Small Blind", "player3" is the "button".....

I want to sort players array, when changePositions(dealer) is called. Example:

```
changePosition(10); //means that "player10" now is the new Dealer
```

And the result should be:

```
players:[2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3];
positions:["bb","sb","btn","late","medium","medium","medium","early","early","early"];
```

During the game, players could be eliminated. So I have a function to exclude "last position" in "positions array" and exclude the player. Then I need to call changePosition(X) again, where X is the next non-eliminated player on the left of "player10" (actual dealer).

Example for eliminated "player 1", new arrays should be:

```
players:[2,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3];
positions:["bb","sb","btn","late","medium","medium","medium","early","early"];
```

And I need to call changePosition(X) again, to determine new positions, in this case X=2, because "player2" is on the left of the actual dealer "player10"

```
changePosition(2);
```

And should result:

```
players:[4,3,2,10,9,8,7,6,5];
positions:["bb","sb","btn","late","medium","medium","medium","early","early"];
```

**How can I find the new dealer when player is eliminated?**

> Note: I created a function named **changeNextDealer()**. Negative index was not the problem, because the next dealer is clockwise. It's in the code pen link.

```
dealerArrayPosition-1; //But if bigBlind and smallBlind was eliminated simultaneously I get a negative position.
```

**How can I map a negative index like -1, to the last position. Or -2 to the LastPosition-1? Is there a quickly way?**

> Note: This question is still no answered, but is not the main question of this discussion. I think a will ask in a separated post.

**How should I do the changePosition(dealer) function?**

I have tried so much, but can't figure out how to do that.

> Note: I created a function named **changePosition()**. It's in the codepen link.

Comment: So you already have implemented `changePosition`?

Comment: That's the main question. I'm trying to do. The most dificult to me is the fact that is a "circle list", and I'm stucked with the negative positions. I'm doing "if conditions" to check if position is negative. If the position is negative I'm getting this: "bbPosition = playersInTable.length + bbPosition" when bbPosition < 0

Comment: Then show your code that is not working.

Comment: http://codepen.io/eMineiro/pen/EKrNBe (Code ready and working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the players are always numbered 1-10. We don't need two data structures to store the player positions and statuses. We only need one indexed data structure to store player state:

**State 1**

```
positions:["btn","sb","bb","early","early","early","medium","medium","medium","late"];
```

**State 2**

```
positions: ["late","btn","sb","bb","early","early","early","medium","medium","medium"]
```

**State 3**

```
positions: ["eliminated","late","btn","sb","bb","early","early","early","medium","medium"];
```

This stores the same amount of information as your two arrays, and is more consistent. You simply access `positions[0]` to see what player 1's state is or `positions[9]` for player 10.

Now with this more consistent structure, it should be easier to handle status changes at the end of each round.

**Eliminating players**

After each round, change an eliminated player's status to `"eliminated"`. You may need to have a temporary array at this point so that you can check what has happened in the previous round will still updating information for the next round.

**How to treat the array as a circle**

Move the dealer chip `"btn"` to `(currentPositionOfBtn+1)%10` - this means the Button moves from 1 to 2 to 3, etc., but by using the remainder operator and the total number of players, we ensure that the move from position 9 (Player 10) cycles back round to 0 (Player 1).

If the player in `currentPositionOfBtn+1)%10` has been eliminated, then check `currentPositionOfBtn+2)%10` and so on - this is an easy loop to implement.

**Recalculating the positions**

Now given that the description of the positions changes as players are eliminated (by the end you have no "early" or "medium"), I would suggest recalculating the positions from the Dealer onwards at the end of each round, skipping over any players who are marked as "eliminated".

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention. Still reading, understanding and coding to see if this will work 100% correct. I believe this will work.

Comment: http://codepen.io/eMineiro/pen/EKrNBe (Thanks for your help, see examples in console.